# Firebase: using "in" as an alternative to "OR" query

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm starting using firebase and I was reading that we cannot use `or` conditions in queries. There are some alternatives to it including mixing queries in client-side or using `array-contains`. And more recently `in` was added to the docs. I tried using `in` in my case but I cannot use more than one of it.

My web application has **client users** and **Profissional hosters** registered. When a hoster logs into the application he needs to get all the messages from all the clients that have sent a message to him.

My docs at firebase are like so:

[image]

Where `uid` is the logged-in user sending a message to the hoster (`memberID`). In this case, `memberID` is the hoster id.

The query I was trying to do is:

- get all messages sent to me as a hoster where `memberID` is my id and
  all messages that I've sent where uid is my id
- get all messages sent to the client where memberID would be client id and all messages that the client has sent where uid is the client id.

Firebase:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('private-messages')
.where('uid', 'in', [`${this.clientID}`, `${this.hosterID}`])
.where('memberID', 'in', [`${this.clientID}`, `${this.hosterID}`])
.orderBy('date').onSnapshot(res => {
    let messages = [];
    res.forEach(doc => {
        messages.push(doc.data());
    });
    this.myMessages = messages;
});
```

Is there a way to do that in firebase?

Comment: Just do two separate queries

Comment: It's not clear to me why these all need to be part of the same query.  It sounds like you have two different sets of data requiring two different queries.

Comment: Yes I did two queries but I need to order them by date to list the messages in order in message box. But all client's messages was listing first and then hoster's messages

Comment: You may order query results with a statement similar to: 
const lastThreeRes = await citiesRef.orderBy('name', 'desc').limit(3).get();
This is offered as an example on the [Order and limit data with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#node.js_1) documentation page.